# How to implement "Username and Password Flow "

Tags: dotnetopenauth

I'm using latest code from "dotnetopenauth" library downloaded from Git.

I didn't find an example to satisfy OAuth2.0 "Username and Password Flow"
basically same case as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676911/how-does-one-generate-access-tokens-programmatically-with-dotnetopenauth-4-so-th)

EDIT:
I guess ExchangeUserCredentialForTokenAsync within DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase is what I'm looking for: I have been able to get an access token explicitly using Token endopint directly from the client.